# Disproof of Four Color Theorem (?)

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I heard about the four color theorem recently and decided to give disproving it a try. After about an hour attempting to disprove [this map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiXdM.png), I couldn't find any solutions with only four colors. Can anyone find any possible way to color it in four colors?

Comment: Questions of this nature are too broad to be considered on-topic here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sorry, but you're not going to get anywhere. The four-color theorem has a proof which has been checked at least as well, if not better, than any other mathematical result.

Here is a coloring.

[image]

Comment: If it is proven, why is it still called a theorem? Is there some particular difference between a proof and a theorem?

Comment: A theorem is precisely something that has been proven. You may be confusing "theorem" with "theory".

Answer (score 3):

[image: This is how I did it]

There's a lot of cool resources on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem) and others about how best to color maps using only 4 colors.